# Python repeating wrong username loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a system that checks for a user name in a separate text file, and if it doesn't exist tell them this and prompt them to re enter the password. This works the first time they get the username incorrect, however subsequent times it repeats the message multiple times.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
def existingUser():

    annoyingProblem = 0

    print("Welcome back")

    while True:
        existingUsername = input("What is your user name?")
        for i in range(100):

            with open("logins.txt", "r") as logins2:

                for num, line in enumerate(logins2, 1):
                    if existingUsername in line:
                        correctPassword()
                else:
                    if annoyingProblem == 99:
                        print("That doesn't seem to match. Please try again")
                    else:
                        annoyingProblem = annoyingProblem + 1
```

Comment: What is that loop supposed to do: `for i in range(100)`?

Comment: your indentation is probably the issue here. You've declared an `else` to a `for` loop, which is legal but probably not what you want. Please confirm the correct indentation.

Comment: _or_ you know what it means, in that case, you have to `break` after calling `correctPassword`, else the `else` will be executed no matter what.

Comment: why are you looping 100 times ?

Comment: @SandeepLade I'm not actually sure as that was the problem!

Comment: @HarryTaylor : Check my answer and see if that addresses your probllem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to check whether the given username is valid , and if its wrong you want give 99 chances to user

**input.txt**

```
sandeep
lade
venkat
```

**Code**(here max chances are 3)

```
def existingUser():

annoyingProblem = 0

print("Welcome back")
while True:
    existingUsername = str(raw_input("What is your user name?"))
    with open("infile.txt", "r") as logins2:

            for num, line in enumerate(logins2, 1):
                if existingUsername in line:
                    correctPassword()

            print("That doesn't seem to match. Please try again")
            annoyingProblem = annoyingProblem + 1
            if annoyingProblem == 3:
                print("exceeded number of attempts")
                break
```

Output

```
>>> existingUser()
Welcome back
What is your user name?nope
That doesn't seem to match. Please try again
What is your user name?nope
That doesn't seem to match. Please try again
What is your user name?nope
That doesn't seem to match. Please try again
exceeded number of attempts
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know how that compiles, as long as you have an "else" in a different tab column than the "if". Maybe that can be your problem, as you are testing things in a way you don't want. Also, existing username is read once and is not changed. So the "if" will be true a hundred times!

Comment: You were right, the else was in the wrong position but sadly that didn't fix the problem

Comment: See what I wrote in the third and fourth sentences @HarryTaylor

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have to use all the looping stuff. As each username is a line.. we can use the below as the file probably will not be huge.. like 100mb..

```
def existingUser():
    existingUsername = input("What is your user name?")
    if existingUsername in open('logins.txt').read():
       correctPassword()
    else:
       print("That doesn't seem to match. Please try again")
```